# Can someone tell me what these cocoons are?

Tags: species-identification, botany

I am camping in Slovenia and have found some cocoon like materials.
They look like nests of some kind and are about 30cm long and 10-15 cm wide. Can anyone help me find out what these things are?
Found in Tolmin, Slovenia

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are actually looking at dried bottle gourds, a squash relative.  These are probably in the genus *Lageneria*.  These come in an extreme variety of shapes, and have been put to many ornamental uses. They were important as containers for early cultures.  Good background [here](https://www2.palomar.edu/users/warmstrong/ww0503.htm#lagenaria) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagenaria).  Search for "dried bottle gourd" images and you'll see plenty.